# Performing the same operation on multiple text files

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, iteration

Assume the following example is from a text file named `Unit1Data.txt`:

```
   32  2020-04-28 09:15:11.98       99
   33  2020-04-28 09:15:27.87       22
  NEW  2020-04-28 09:56:31.89       9
                        Total  73749

Upload #29, 45392 records
Unit: Unit1  Location: AA11
--------- upload 29 start ---------
U 2011-09-20 14:06:20.78 upload 28 complete
D 2017-04-19 09:11:59.00 00:01:02.30 HR 0000_0000000162946581 A24    8     7
D 2017-04-19 09:12:02.25 00:00:01.00 HR 0000_0000000161638293 A22    3     3
```

I wrote the following script which extracts data from lines that start with `D` and adds a column to denote the `Unit` which can be found on the line of the text file that starts with "Unit" (I did it this way because its not always the same line, but it always starts with "Unit"). Finally it converts the data to a csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

un = []# to store unit name

with open('Unit1Data.txt', 'r') as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if line.startswith("Unit"):
            un.append(line.split()[1])

EmptyString = ""
val = str(un)
val = re.sub(r'[\w\s]', EmptyString, val)
print(val)

out = []#to store output
with open('Unit1Data.txt', 'r') as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if line.startswith("D"):
            out.append(line.split()[0:])

data = pd.DataFrame(out,
                    columns=['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9'])
#I have more meaningful column names this is just for example

data['Unit'] = val
print(data)

data.to_csv('Test.csv', index=False)
```

Lets assume the example text file above came from "Unit1". I have a separate text files with the same structure for "Unit2" and "Unit3" (we will call these text files "Unit2Data.txt", and "Unit3Data.txt" respectively). I want to perform these same operations on all 3 text files, but I want to combine the data for all 3 units into a single csv (not 3 separate ones). Assuming these 3 files are stored in my working directory (`C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyProject`), could someone demonstrate how one could combine the two for loops (possibly performing the same operation within a user defined function), and how to iterate the operation over multiple txt files which are stored in the users working directory using python3 syntax?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can restructure the code as a function, which takes as input a filename, and produces a dataframe.

After that, you can use python's `glob` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) (e.g. `glob.glob('C:Users\Me\Desktop\MyProject\*')` to get a list of files.

Lastly, you need to combine the 3 dataframes into a single dataframe, which you can then call `to_csv` on.
For merging, take a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to iterate over a list of chosen files.
If you need help with the full program upgrade, you'll need to work with available tutorials and examples; that problem is too broad for Stack Overflow.

```
file_list = [
    'Unit1Data.txt',
    'Unit2Data.txt',
    'Unit3Data.txt',
    ...  # Fill in whatever files you want to use
]

for unit_file in file_list:
    with open(unit_file, 'r') as fi:
        # Continue with the rest of your code
```